# Python LDAP module with pass thru authentication?

Tags: python-3.x, ldap

I need to query Active Directory using Python.  I would typically do this with an LDAP package, however I also do not want to hard code my credentials for active directory into the script.  The script will be exceuted by an Active Directory account, are there any LDAP modules that will do pass through authentication and bind to the directory using the credentials of the account executing the script without specifying the username + password in the script?

PowerShell can do this, and most LDAP GUI clients have an option to authenticate as the Windows user running the client, is there a package for python that can query LDAP that auths the same way?